# Copy lines from .csv file into another .csv file using batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file, vbscript

I am creating .csv files from a device (output) and need to copy a specific number of lines from this file into another .csv file which has the same format.

They are luckily the same format and so each file has the same lines to copy over (line 68 to 107). I have had a go at this using code from other sources but all I have been able to do so far is to copy out the data but am unable to insert it into the other file. Any help would be great!

```
@echo off

Set "InputFile=C:\*****\Desktop\Dev\Test\Default.csv"
Set "OutPutFile=C:\*****\Desktop\Dev\Test\OutputData.csv"
Set FromLine=68
Set ToLine=107

Call:ExtractLinesFromTextFile "%InputFile%" %FromLine% %ToLine% > 
"%OutPutFile%"

Exit /b

:ExtractLinesFromTextFile <InputFile> <FromLine> <ToLine>
(
echo Wscript.echo(ExtractLinesFromTextFile("%~1",%2,%3^)^)
echo Function ExtractLinesFromTextFile(TextFile,FromLine,ToLine^)
echo If FromLine ^<= ToLine Then
echo With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^).OpenTextFile(TextFile^)
echo Do Until .Line = FromLine Or .AtEndOfStream
echo .SkipLine
echo Loop
echo Do Until .Line ^> ToLine Or .AtEndOfStream
echo ExtractLinesFromTextFile = ExtractLinesFromTextFile ^& (.ReadLine ^& 
vbNewLine^)
echo Loop
echo End With
echo End If
echo End Function
)>"%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /Nologo "%~n0.vbs" "%~1" %~2 %~3
If Exist "%~n0.vbs" Del "%~n0.vbs"
Exit /b
```

Comment: It's utterly pointless to write a batch file that does nothing but create and invoke a VBScript. Remove the batch code and write VBScript directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate why you don't want to do this in batch, this is the code to copy lines 68 through 107 to another file in VBScript:

```vb
inputFilename  = "C:\path\to\input.csv"
outputFilename = "C:\path\to\output.csv"
fromLine = 68
toLine   = 107

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFilename)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFilename, 2, True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream Or inFile.Line > toLine
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  If inFile.Line >= fromLine Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

To illustrate why you don't want to do this in VBScript either, this is the same operation in PowerShell:

```bsh
$inputFile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outputFile = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
$fromLine   = 68
$toLine     = 107

$skip       = $fromLine - 1
$numLines   = $toLine - $skip

Get-Content $inputFile | Select-Object -Skip $skip -First $numLines |
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

which could be simplified to:

```bsh
$inputFile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outputFile = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
$skip       = 67
$numLines   = 40

Get-Content $inputFile | Select-Object -Skip $skip -First $numLines |
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

You can even preserve the CSV header if you want:

```bsh
$inputFile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outputFile = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
$skip       = 66
$numLines   = 40

Import-Csv $inputFile | Select-Object -Skip $skip -First $numLines |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
```

Comment: Yeah, I see now that I was doing it super inefficient. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to use a batch file that creates and invokes a VBScript.

---

You could accomplish the task by a pure batch script like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILEIN=!USERPROFILE!\Desktop\Dev\Test\Default.csv"
set "_FILEOUT=!USERPROFILE!\Desktop\Dev\Test\OutputData.csv"
set /A "_LINEFROM=68"
set /A "_LINETO=107"

rem // Count number of lines of input file:
for /F %%C in ('^< "!_FILEIN!" find /C /V ""') do (
    rem // Read and write files using redirection:
    < "!_FILEIN!" > "!_FILEOUT!" (
        rem // Iterate through all available lines:
        for /L %%I in (1,1,%%C) do (
            rem // Read a single line:
            set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
            rem // Check position (line number) of current line:
            if %%I GEQ %_LINEFROM% if %%I LEQ %_LINETO% (
                rem // Return current line conditionally:
                echo(!LINE!
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that pure batch file solutions may be limited in line lengths and file sizes. The aforementioned approach cannot handle lines longer than 1023 bytes and files with more than 2147483647 lines.

---

Here is another but slower pure batch script solution:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILEIN=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dev\Test\Default.csv"
set "_FILEOUT=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Dev\Test\OutputData.csv"
set /A "_LINEFROM=68"
set /A "_LINETO=107"

rem // Write file using redirection:
> "%_FILEOUT%" (
    rem // Read file using a loop, prefixed with line index:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILEIN%"') do (
        rem // Extract line number:
        2> nul set /A "IDX=%%L"
        rem // Read current line:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check position (line number) of current line:
        if !IDX! GEQ %_LINEFROM% if !IDX! LEQ %_LINETO% (
            rem // Return current line conditionally:
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach cannot handle lines longer than 8191 - 7 = 8184 bytes and files with more than 2147483647 lines.

Comment: Why not use the `for /f` to parse/split at the colon? That would give an one liner in cmd `(for /f "skip=67tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('findstr /N "^" ^<InFile.csv') Do @if %A LEQ 107 @Echo %B)>OutFile.csv`

Comment: I wanted to provide a general solution; an approach using `for /F "delims=:"` removed leading colons from lines, because subsequent delimiters are treated like one...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have been playing around with batch files recently hence why I thought I could use it but probably better to use other formats.