# How to read particular range to last line of file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How to read particular range of line ie if my file have 100 lines and I want to read the lines from 80 to last line of file using PowerShell?here I'm not sure about how many lines are available in the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy lines from .csv file into another .csv file using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038462/copy-lines-from-csv-file-into-another-csv-file-using-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it :

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt" | select -skip 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just get the last 20 lines:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\test.txt' -Tail 20
```

If you want to find out how many lines the file has so that you can use that to decide what to read, this could help:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\test.txt'
$lines.count
```

So if you decide you want to get for example the last half of the lines you could do something like this:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\test.txt'
$half = [math]::Round($lines.count/2)
Select-Object -InputObject $lines -Last $half
```